# The fastest way to check all values from the list of coordinates

Tags: performance, numpy

I have a list of coordinates `a = [(1,2),(1,300),(2,3).....]`
These values area coordinates of `1000 x 1000 NumPy` array.

Let's say I want to sum all the values under these coordinates. Is there a faster way to do it than:

```
sum([array[i[0],i[1]] for i in a])
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a mask to `array` using `a` and then sum over the masked array. Example:

```
# Prepare sample array and indices
a = np.arange(10*10).reshape(10,10)
ind = [(1,0), (2, 4), (2,6), (7,7), (8,9), (9,3)]

# Cast list of coordinates into a form that will work for indexing
indx = np.split(np.array(ind), 2, axis = 1)

# A warning may be raised about not using tuples for indexing. You can use tuple(indx) to avoid that.
np.sum(a[indx])
```